# Unity AppOpenAd

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, google-ads-api, googleads-mobile-unity

I want to add open ads to my game that I developed on Unity, but the type 'AppOpenAd' or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?) I get an [Assembly-CSharp] error. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: Did you use latest googleads unity plugins ?? according to documentation they added AppOpedAd support in latest build

Comment: In the project I use, there is old google ads and all the codes are adapted accordingly. Is it possible to update this package from within Unity?

Comment: No I don't think you can update within Unity. you need to download new package